# How to access the column of joined entity using JPA Specification?

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I am creating a **specification** which returns the **Parent** entity's records based on **Child** entity's **type** column. These 2 entities have One-to-One mapping, so I am joining them.

But the problem is that type column is inside the **embedded id** of Child entity.

My code snippet is below:

```
return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Join<Parent, Child> join = root.join("child");
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("id.type"), val);
    };
```

I haven't got any success with it yet. How do I access the type column correctly to make my code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following code makes it work -

```
return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    Join<Parent, Child> join = root.join("child");
    Join<Child, ChildPK> joinId = join.join("id");
    return criteriaBuilder.equal(joinId.get("type"), val);
};
```

Here ChildPK is the **embedded id**.